# POST request to receive redirect on client side

Tags: javascript, post, redirect, fetch

I have a service running that receives a POST request and returns a redirect. I have been able to test this using Postman and nghttp2.org (httpbin.org).

On postman, when I POST:

```
https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/redirect-to?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

The html received is google.com homepage

However to run this on a client side webpage I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function redirect() {
            fetch('https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/redirect-to?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com', {
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'text/html',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                },
                method: 'POST', 
                mode: 'no-cors',
                redirect: 'follow',
            })
        }

        redirect();

    </script>
</html>
```

I am running this webpage on a server, and it is not redirecting.

Is it possible to get the page to redirect automatically when this webpage is loaded?
Or is there another approach I could make. I do need the request to be a POST and I do need the redirect to happen on client side due to cookie handling.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: A redirect in a fetch request will never redirect the page , only the fetch request itself. Then fetch is subject to CORS restrictions that Rest clients like Postman are not. Google will not enable CORS on their home page so the request shown will fail. To do a client side redirect use `location.href = url`

Comment: @charlietfl Cheers, I have changed the redirect url to a local address on my network, I am looking at the response after posting and it says that redirected is false and that the status is 0, any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch doesn't directly redirect to another page requested by the server. But it can tell you that the server is requesting for redirect to another page and you can handle that accordingly. You can find more info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected